# Matrix operation, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have the following problem:

> Find all the matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ such that $AX + B = BX + A$ 
>   [image]

I didn't know how to face the problem so I did the "long manually way".
[image]

[image]

So I ended up finding the identity matrix (which now its kind of expected because $A.I + B = B.I + A <=> A + B = B + A$ )

So my question is: How can I prove ii) that the only $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ Matrix is the identity matrix without going for the same calculations?, is there a more efficient way to do it?

Thanks for reading and Sorry for my english!

Comment: The equation can be rewritten as $(A-B)(X-I)=0$. Therefore $X=I+[v_1|v_2]$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are any two solutions to the equation $(A-B)v=0$. In particular, if $A-B$ happens to be nonsingular, $v_1$ and $v_2$ must be zero and hence $X=I$.